# redirect (mod_rewrite) specific page to new domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect a group of pages to new domain but so far I'm just not able make it happen.

I want any request which begins with:

`http://www.mydomain.com/wiki/index.php?title=CSV_to_QuickBooks_Converter`

to be redirected to:

`www.StatementConverter.com`

*Example:*

`http://www.mydomain.com/wiki/index.php?title=CSV_to_QuickBooks_Converter_-_ABCXYZ`

should be permanently redirected to:

`http://www.StatementConverter.com`

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
# Prevent viewing of the .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# Cache files for one month
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# trying to redirect these pages to new website
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)CSV_to_QuickBooks_Converter$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.statementconverter.com/ [R,L]
```

So far, the original page displays (my rule is not applied).

**SOLUTION:**

Incorporating the answers I received, I'm using this and it works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=CSV_Statement_to_QuickBooks_Converter [NC] 
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://statementconverter.com/? [R,L]
```

I added "?" at the end of the RewriteRule to prevent the original query_string from being appended to the new URL.

Comment: Incorporating both answers, this is what I'm using:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=CSV_Statement_to_QuickBooks_Converter [NC]

RewriteRule ^.*$ http://statementconverter.com/? [R,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the ^ and $ characters. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \btitle=CSV_to_QuickBooks_Converter [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.statementconverter.com/? [R,L]
```

Do not send 301 redirects until you've tested the rules thoroughly and ready to go live. 301 redirects are cached by browsers and search engines. While you can clear your browser cache after making changes to your redirect rules, you cannot always tell search engines to come back because you've changed the redirect URLs.

Comment: I've revised my answer and added a `?`. This should clear the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any request which *begins* with that URL to be redirected, do not anchor the regexp in the `RewriteCond`!

You have:

```
# trying to redirect these pages to new website
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)CSV_to_QuickBooks_Converter$ [NC]
                                                            ^ anchored to exact match!
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.statementconverter.com/ [R,L]
```

Does the exact URL `...CSV_to_QuickBooks_Converter` also not redirect?

Also, do a shift-reload if you're using a browser to test this; maybe you are falling victim to cachin.

BTW `^(.*)` is pointless! Anchor to the beginning, but then munch any character any number of times allowing the rest to match anywhere in the string! :)  Also pointless are the parentheses since you aren't using the captured text or applying a regex operator to the parenthesized group. (It's just a habit because capturing `(.*)` into `$1` comes up so often, right? Haha.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy paste this:

```
# Prevent viewing of the .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Cache files for one month
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# trying to redirect these pages to new website
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)title=CSV_to_QuickBooks_Converter [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.statementconverter.com/ [R,L]
```

And tell me if it works